# Min b'sh'eino mino requires bitul b'shishim rather than bitul b'rov, d'rabbanan or d'oraisa?

Tags: taarovet

The rule that min b'sh'eino mino requires bitul b'shishim rather than bitul b'rov, is this d'rabbanan or d'oraisa?

Comment: For the sake of outsiders, we try to avoid [unnecessary jargon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/site-policy-on-jargon) at Mi Yodeya. If possible, please try to find an English equivalent to make your post more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is if the taste that comes out of an item needs sixty times it size to nullify it *min haTorah*, then your question really is, is *Ta"am k'ikur M'Dioraysa*.

That is a three way Machlokes in the Rishonim, based on the Gemorah in Pesachim 44b,

(1) it is from the Torah and you would get the same punishment as the original forbidden food,

(2) it is from the Torah but you do not get malkus on just the taste, or

(3) it is only m'dirabonon.

Here is how the sefer קובץ יסודות וחקירות summarizes it:

[image]

Comment: Actually my question is if one eats b’mezid God forbid stam non-kosher ground beef or non-kosher beef hot dogs or Hebrew National hot dogs or non-kosher ground sirloin or round or McDonald's french fries which are known to be fried in beef fat, would he God forbid get kares because of the cheilev issue?  Or no, because the cheilev would be batel b'rov d'oraisa, considering that the chelev and the non-chelev in the hot dog are min b'mino since the fat and meat are ground up together and it's lach b'lach?  Or maybe they are min b'sh'eino mino, and you would need batel b'shishim?

Comment: But my question is, is the entire inyan of min b'sh'eino mino d'rabbanan, so even if the chelev and the non-chelev in the mixture were min b'sh'eino mino, still the chelev would be batel d'oraisa?

Comment: @jonahalpen I would be shocked if Hebrew National hotdogs contained cheilev

Comment: @jonahalpen - You are making an assumption that Cheilev and meat are not the same "min". That is actually a discussion in the Shach YD 88/1. Assuming it is min b'sh'ayno mino, then it would depend on the Rishonim mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Rambam Hilchot Maachalot Assurot 15:1-2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968271/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-15.htm):

> When a forbidden substance becomes mixed with a permitted substance of another type, [it causes it to become forbidden] if its flavor can be detected...
>
> What is implied? When the fat of the kidneys falls into beans and becomes dissolved, the beans should be tasted. If the taste of fat cannot be detected, they are permitted. If [not only] the taste, [but also] the substance of the fat is present, they are forbidden according to Scriptural Law. If the flavor could be detected, but there is no substance, they are forbidden by Rabbinic Law.

In paragraph 3 Rambam goes on to define what he means by ‘substance’, and in paragraph 30 to discuss what to do if there is no one available to taste the suspect mixture (which often involves estimating based on a ratio of 1:60).